# time wrong on sdcard images in Ubuntu, okay on camera and Windows

Tags: sd-card, time

when i take a picture and put the sdcard in my Ubuntu 18.10, the picture date is 6-hrs ago. but if i look at it in my panasonic camera, the time is correct. if i look at it in windows, the time is correct. if i try a different camera, a canon, and different sdcard, same thing, 6-hrs earlier. date and time on Ubuntu is correct. date and time on the cameras are correct. i tried formatting the sdcards. what's going on?

this picture was taken at 8:03pm, but properties says modified at 2:03pm, exif data says correctly 8:03pm.
[image: screenshot]

My time zone is CST, central.

Comment: What's your local time zone?

Comment: CST, central. i double-checked that setting

Answer (score 2):

The FAT filesystem does not store the timezone, and the specification does not say whether timestamps should be taken as UTC (as on any other filesystem) or as local time. Windows interprets timestamps on FAT filesystems as being in the current local timezone. Linux, by default, interprets them as UTC.

Example: The timestamp on the file says 8:03. Linux believes this to be UTC. Your local timezone is 6 hours behind (that is, west of) UTC, so Linux displays this as 2:03 local time.

Mount the filesystem with `-o time_offset=-360` to tell the kernel that timestamps on the FAT filesystem are to be considered 6 hours behind UTC. See the [manual page of the `mount` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/mount.8.html#filesystem-specific%20mount%20options) for details.

Comment: thanks, makes sense now. but the sdcard seems to automount when it is inserted. do i need to mount it again elsewhere with the time_offset each time i insert it? or is there a way to make the time_offset permanent?

Comment: @ticotexas: Yep. `sudo umount /dev/sdb1 && sudo mount -o uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),quiet,fmask=0133,dmask=0022,time_offset=-360 /dev/sdb1 /mnt` should do the trick. Replace `/dev/sdb1` as needed and `/mnt` according to taste. If your locale has daylight saving time then when daylight saving time is in effect you may want to replace `-360` with `-300`. Remember to `sudo umount /dev/sdb1` before removing the card.