# Time shift on images copied from Canon camera, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: mount, canon, sd-card

Taking an SD card from a Canon camera, it appears the times on Nautilus and another file manager are shifted by 4 hours *earlier* than what is seen on the 'Image' properties tab (which is the correct time).

Camera and laptop are both EDT (UTC-4).

From this:

[time wrong on sdcard images in Ubuntu, okay on camera and Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097568/time-wrong-on-sdcard-images-in-ubuntu-okay-on-camera-and-windows)

and

[SD Card reporting Date created in the future](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424436/sd-card-reporting-date-created-in-the-future)

... it seems there is an issue with the mount.  The first note above mentions the command line, the second, for use with the Disks widget.

However, when using the Disks widget, and adding the time_offset=600 element, you must shut off the 'user defaults', and therefore, the SD card mounts as root.

What would be the workaround here?

Comment: Correction, yes; this on EDT, not EST; changed this in the original question.   Camera pictures taken at 10:30 AM originally showed up as taken at 6:30 AM.

Comment: Please do not use comments to add info to the question. At the bottom of the question is the edit tab. Please use this and add the info to the question. Comments are where the people trying to help you ask for more info.